# wordpress: touchpad (2-finger) scrolling not working in IE 11 / Edge browser

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have a wordpress website that I am working on (https://52.6.239.159/).
The website works fine when browsed from Chrome/Firefox/Safari.

I have a windows 10 laptop (dell xps 13). If I navigate to the website from the windows 10 laptop using IE 11 or Edge, 2-finger scroll using the the touchpad does not work on any page. If I use the mousewheel or the keyboard arrow keys, scrolling works and I can see the entire page.

Can someone help me with why touchpad scrolling is not working from IE?

I am new to the web development. Is there something very obvious that I am missing here?

Comment: [link](http://caniuse.com/#search=touch) check out this for the features that work in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by forcing the page to always show scrollbar. This is not ideal, but at least does the job.

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll !important; 
}
```